# How to select specific rows based on a logic in a grouped-by data?

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, sparkr

I have the following data in Hive:

```
id  sequence app    time1                time2                 first_d_seq  last_d_seq
2456    1      a    10/11/2018 10:25:43  10/11/2018 10:25:47   5            6
2456    2      b    10/11/2018 10:25:48  10/11/2018 10:25:55   5            6
2456    3      b    10/11/2018 10:25:58  10/11/2018 10:26:02   5            6
2456    4      c    10/11/2018 10:26:02  10/11/2018 10:26:08   5            6
2456    5      d    10/11/2018 10:26:08  10/11/2018 10:26:13   5            6
2456    6      d    10/11/2018 10:26:15  10/11/2018 10:26:20   5            6
2456    7      f    10/11/2018 10:26:20  10/11/2018 10:26:28   5            6
2456    8      f    10/11/2018 10:26:32  10/11/2018 10:26:39   5            6
9702    1      a    10/11/2018 11:05:14  10/11/2018 11:05:16   3            3
9702    2      b    10/11/2018 11:05:16  10/11/2018 11:05:20   3            3
9702    3      d    10/11/2018 11:05:20  10/11/2018 11:05:25   3            3
9702    4      h    10/11/2018 11:05:25  10/11/2018 11:05:27   3            3
9702    5      f    10/11/2018 11:05:27  10/11/2018 11:05:36   3            3
```

for which I know where app `d` starts and ends in the sequence for each `id` group (i.e., for the first group `d` starts at sequence=5 and ends at sequence=6).

What I'd like to calculate, for each `id` group, are **1)** time spent from the very beginning (`sequence=1`) till the first appearance of `d` (`sequence = first_d_seq - 1`), and **2)** time spent from right after `d` (`sequence = last_d_seq + 1`) till the end of sequence for that id (i.e., `8` for id = 2456; and `5` for id = 9702).

Essentially, the output should be like this:

```
id      before_d    after_d
2456    25          19
9702    6           11
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried creating the last two columns which I thought it could be useful. After that, have tried using 'Having' statement in combination with sequencenumber to sort of chopping only rows that are between the defined range but that did not work since it needed sequencenumber to be in group by statement or a aggregate function. Also looked into Hive window function but not able to figure out how to use them in this example.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague, we figured out the following solution:

```
with x as ( --raw data table
select stack(13,
2456,1,'a','10/11/2018 10:25:43','10/11/2018 10:25:47',5,6,
2456,2,'b','10/11/2018 10:25:48','10/11/2018 10:25:55',5,6,
2456,3,'b','10/11/2018 10:25:58','10/11/2018 10:26:02',5,6,
2456,4,'c','10/11/2018 10:26:02','10/11/2018 10:26:08',5,6,
2456,5,'d','10/11/2018 10:26:08','10/11/2018 10:26:13',5,6,
2456,6,'d','10/11/2018 10:26:15','10/11/2018 10:26:20',5,6,
2456,7,'f','10/11/2018 10:26:20','10/11/2018 10:26:28',5,6,
2456,8,'f','10/11/2018 10:26:32','10/11/2018 10:26:39',5,6,
9702,1,'a','10/11/2018 11:05:14','10/11/2018 11:05:16',3,3,
9702,2,'b','10/11/2018 11:05:16','10/11/2018 11:05:20',3,3,
9702,3,'d','10/11/2018 11:05:20','10/11/2018 11:05:25',3,3,
9702,4,'h','10/11/2018 11:05:25','10/11/2018 11:05:27',3,3,
9702,5,'f','10/11/2018 11:05:27','10/11/2018 11:05:36',3,3
) as (id,sequence,app,time1,time2,first_d_seq,last_d_seq)
) -- select * from x
,

y as (
select id,
min(sequence)-1 as min_seq, 
max(sequence)+1 as max_seq
from x
where app='d'
group by id
) -- select * from y
,

z as (
select id,
min(time1) as mintime_all,
max(time2) as maxtime_all
--min(unix_timestamp(startdtm, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as mintime_all,
--max(unix_timestamp(enddtm, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')) as maxtime_all
from x
group by id
) --select * from z


select x1.id,
( unix_timestamp(x1.time2, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - unix_timestamp(z.mintime_all, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') ) as before_d,
( unix_timestamp(z.maxtime_all, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - unix_timestamp(x2.time1, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') ) as after_d
from y as y
inner join x as x1 on x1.id=y.id and x1.sequence=y.min_seq
inner join x as x2 on x2.id=y.id and x2.sequence=y.max_seq
inner join z as z on y.id=z.id;
```

This will generate the expected answer:

```
  id     before_d   after_d
2456        25           19
9702        6            11
```